# Complete Binary Tree v/s Almost Complete Binary Tree

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

There is no confusion/conflict between definition of Perfect Binary Tree,(Full/Strict/Proper) Binary Tree and Balanced Binary Tree.

**Source 1 (mycodeschool, GeeksForGeeks):**

*Complete Binary Tree:* A Binary Tree is a complete Binary Tree if all the levels are completely filled except possibly the last level and the last level has all keys as left as possible.

*No mention of Almost Complete Binary Tree*

**Source 2 (My teacher, many YouTubers):**

*Almost Complete Binary Tree:* Same definition of Complete Binary tree from Source 1.

*Complete Binary Tree:* Same definition as Perfect Binary Tree, that is it's saying Complete Binary Tree and Perfect Binary Tree are same.

Why there exists different definitions in terminologies? and which source should I consider?

Comment: If you are using such terminology in a document, you should always restate the definition before you use it. Different people have different conventions. "Perfect binary trees" are more of a theory concept - it is almost never encountered in applied data structures, since it is only possible when the number of elements is exactly a power of two minus one. The "almost complete binary tree" on the other hand, can be very useful, for instance when building a heap.

Comment: @Stef Thanks for the answer and I really like that you're applying practicality to the scene, but if someone asks me to tell about Complete Binary tree what am I supposed to say? should I give both the answers like "Different sources have different definition ....." and then give both definition or go with a particular source listed above?

Comment: I would pick just one definition, but mention which one you're using first, to remove all ambiguity. If your interlocutor then interrupts you to say they want the other definition, then use the other definition instead. Also, if there is context to the discussion, maybe you can try to guess which definition was most relevant.

Comment: Very similar: [What are nearly complete binary trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59972973/5459839)